# Optimizely not getting activated for Java SDK code

Tags: java, optimizely

I'm trying to use the below code from the Optimizely docs :

```
Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
attributes.put("device", "iPhone");
attributes.put("lifetime", 24738388);
attributes.put("is_logged_in", true);

Boolean enabled = optimizelyClient.isFeatureEnabled("new_feature", "user123", attributes);
```

In the [optimizely api](http://optimizely.com) , I have the experiment setup as "new_feature" with variation key as "var1" and user attributes for audience targeting with those above attributes. I have whitelisted the user123. But I don't think my experiment is getting activated or receiving any traffic. Am I missing anything here? Any hints are helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`isFeaturerEnabled` is the API for feature flags.

You can set up experiments as [standalone objects](https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/full-stack/docs/run-a-b-tests) or as experiments on [feature flags](https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/full-stack/docs/run-feature-tests).

If you only want to activate a user for a standalone experiment, you will use `activate(experimentKey, userID)`.

If you want to activate a user for an experiment on a feature flag, you can use `isFeatureEnabled` like you are now.

More in depth information on activate API [here](https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/full-stack/docs/activate-java)

Comment: we basically wanted to run A/B test on the experiment , not the feature test. Could you please tell me if that is possible with the above logic?

Comment: Yes. You can run it as a stand-alone experiment using activate as described previously.